# Canvas getRight method returns Nan

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a Rectangle that I am trying to drag and drop inside a Canvas. After the drag is complete I want to get the left, top, right and bottom coordinates. For that when I say Canvas.GetRight(dragableThumb) and Canvas.GetBottom(dragableThumb) it returns NaN for both the values.

So for the right and bottom I am saying something like this, but the problem is I get wrong values. Please help.

var right = this.Width - left - dragableThumb.ActualWidth;
 var bottom = this.Height - top - dragableThumb.ActualHeight;

Here is the entire code.

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="myDragableCT">
            <Rectangle 
x:Name="Arrow" 
Height="94" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="128">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Name="DragableCanvas">
        <Thumb x:Name="dragableThumb" DragDelta="DragableThumb_DragDelta" DragCompleted="DragableThumb_DragCompleted" Canvas.Left="331"
                   Canvas.Top="112" Template="{StaticResource myDragableCT}"></Thumb>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DragableThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(dragableThumb, Canvas.GetLeft(dragableThumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(dragableThumb, Canvas.GetTop(dragableThumb) + e.VerticalChange);
        }

        private void DragableThumb_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var left = Canvas.GetLeft(dragableThumb);
            var top = Canvas.GetTop(dragableThumb);
            var right = this.Width - left - dragableThumb.ActualWidth;
            var bottom = this.Height - top - dragableThumb.ActualHeight;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("left:{0}, top:{1}, right:{2}, bottom:{3}", left, top, right, bottom));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Right` and `Canvas.Bottom` are layout properties instead of render properties. The four properties are used to limit the layout of the `UIElements` but not presents the layout states And this behavior is the same as the `Width` and `Height` properties.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="DemoButton" />
</Grid>
```

See this code above, if we read the `Width` and `Height` properties, we'll find that they are both `double.NaN`. Only if we read the `ActualWidth`, `ActualHeight` or `RenderSize` properties we can get the correct layout states.

The same as the `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Right` and `Canvas.Bottom` properties. You can get the right and the bottom by using other methods, such as:

```cs
var right = Canvas.GetLeft(dragableThumb) + dragableThumb.ActualWidth;
var bottom = Canvas.GetTop(dragableThumb) + dragableThumb.ActualHeight;
```

If you want a method for all other situations you can try this code below:

```
var bounds = new Rect(
    dragableThumb.TranslatePoint(default, DragableCanvas),
    dragableThumb.TranslatePoint(new Point(dragableThumb.ActualWidth, dragableThumb.ActualHeight), DragableCanvas));
var right = bounds.Right;
var bottom = bounds.Bottom;
```

By the way, you spelled the wrong `dragable`. The correct spell is `draggable`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
var right = left + dragableThumb.ActualWidth;
var bottom = top + dragableThumb.ActualHeight;
```